# Regular expression search during Vim replace

Tags: vim, replace

I have many lines in my script that look like:

```bsh
./run -f abc.txt
./run -f abc1.txt
./run -f abc2.txt
..
..
./run -f abc50.txt
```

I need to replace all `abc*.txt` with `abc.txt`. Is there a way in Vim I can do this, where I search for all `abc*.txt` and replace them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
:%s/abc\d*.txt/abc.txt/g
```

Comment: @ZnArK It's not necessary, you could try.

Answer (score 2):

I will add this different way to do it in the name of diversity but I think the standard and simplest way is @xdazz approach.

```
:%g/abc/norm!fclvf.hx
```

When we use `%g` we are applying the commands to all the lines that match the fist argument (in this case `abc` which means all the lines that have `abc` on them). The `norm!` command means *Do the commands like in normal mode* `fc` means find the letter `c`, `l` means go to the left, `v` starts visual mode, `f.` find point, `h` go to the right and finally `x` delete visualized word.

The nice thing about this approach is that you can apply complicated macros to selected lines.

Answer (score 1):

In short try something like:  (may need slight massaging) `%s/abc\d*\.txt/abc\.txt/g`

Check this page out for more info.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace

```
:%s/foo/bar/g
Find each occurrence of 'foo', and replace it with 'bar'.
:%s/foo/bar/gc
Change each 'foo' to 'bar', but ask for confirmation first.
:%s/\<foo\>/bar/gc
Change only whole words exactly matching 'foo' to 'bar'; ask for confirmation.
:%s/foo/bar/gci
Change each 'foo' (case insensitive) to 'bar'; ask for confirmation.
This may be wanted after using :set noignorecase to make searches case sensitive (the default).
```